# Как правильно оформить стих от Матфея?

Tags: оформление-текста

> Люди приходили для участия в совместных трапезах — вечерях любви и
>   единения, или, как их ещё называли, агапэ. Считалось, что радости этих
>   вечерей любви
>   и разделение пищи с родными по вере – предчувствие радости вечной.
>   Храм христианина рождался, обретал черты реальности только в
>   евхаристическом собрании. ***«Ибо, где двое или трое собраны во имя
>   Мое, там Я посреди них», – от Матфея 18:20.***

С отточия ли начинать стих?

Если имя дано развёрнуто, не надо ли указать главу и стих, словами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Храм христианина рождался, обретал обретал черты реальности только в евхаристическом собрании: «Ибо, где двое или трое собраны во имя Мое, там Я посреди них» **(Евангелие от Матфея 18:20).**

**Двоеточие** ставится, так как цитата поясняет первую часть предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно цитаты из Евангелия оформляются сокращённым именем и номерами/номерами стихов в скобках после текста самой цитаты:

> (Матф. 10:18) или даже (Мф. 10:18)
>
> (Лк. 2:10-12)
>
> (Мк. 4:8-14)

Comment: А если у автора Матфей дан полностью? ***Если имя дано развёрнуто, не надо ли указать главу и стих, словами?***

Comment: Этот вопрос уже больше относится к теории перевода, чем к русскому языку.